# unity configuration open generic types

Tags: .net, generics, unity-container

i'm trying to use unity to resolve an generic instance of the `IChannelFactory<ISomeType>` to create channels to a service i have written.

The problem is that the concrete version of this class `ChannelFactory<ISomeType>` takes the concrete type `System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding` as a parameter.

My first problem was that it could not find `System.ServiceModel` but i resolved that by putting the super fully qualified name (including version number etc). So now i can break into the code but it blows up when i try to resolve an `IChannelFactory`

My config is as such:

```
      <!--binding-->
      <type name="customerBinding" type="System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding, System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
        <typeConfig extensionType="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.TypeInjectionElement, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration">
          <constructor>
            <param name="configurationName" parameterType="System.String">
              <value value="CustomerAccountService" />
            </param>                
          </constructor>
        </typeConfig>
      </type>

      <!-- customer account channel factory -->
      <type name="customerChannelFactory" 
            type="System.ServiceModel.Channels.IChannelFactory`1[[ServiceContracts.Customer.ICustomerAccountProvider, ServiceContracts.Customer]], System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL" 
            mapTo="System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1[[ServiceContracts.Customer.ICustomerAccountProvider, ServiceContracts.Customer]], System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
        <typeConfig extensionType="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.TypeInjectionElement, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration">
          <constructor>
            <param name="binding" parameterType="System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding, System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
              <dependency name="customerBinding" />
            </param>
          </constructor>
        </typeConfig>
      </type>
```

The error i get is that it cannot construct the type because it is an interface, even though the mapping to a concrete type is clearly there. Notice i am trying to constrict the type resolution to specific types so it only works with `IChannelFactory<ISomeType>` and not `IChannelFactory<ISomeOtherType>`, for instance. perhaps this isn't ythe correct way to do things?

If i just try to resolve the `Binding` in isolation it says it cannot disambiguate from other constructors taking one parameter (even though i defined the param type  to be string!)

Any ideas or pointers what i am doing wrong here peeps? Or perhaps even a solution ;-)

Thanks

Comment: Glad to see I'm not the only one who can never figure out what's going on whenever I try anything non-trivial with Unity!

Comment: haha i was just reading your question on unity and generics two seconds ago! nice public enemy reference by the way :-)

Comment: Are you resolving with the name of the registration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after much searching it seems that this just may not be possible in unity 1.2? it seems that unity 1.2 does not support open generic types, this feature was introduced in unity 2.0.

see the following:
http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2008/03/25/UnityDependencyInjectionOpenGenericTypes.aspx

if anyone would like to prove otherwise, i'd be most welcome :-)

Comment: Did you notice the date on that blog post? It's 2008! That's talking about a new drop adding the feature in Unity 1.2

Comment: chris, unfortunately we're stuck using 1.1 so that is pertinent here. And there's no easy way i can change to using a newer version quickly :-(

Answer (score 0):

You can configure a generic interface/implementation in this way:

```
<type name="customerChannelFactory" 
            type="System.ServiceModel.Channels.IChannelFactory`1, System.ServiceModel" 
            mapTo="System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1, System.ServiceModel">
        <typeConfig>
          <constructor>
            <param name="binding" parameterType="System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding, System.ServiceModel">
              <dependency name="customerBinding" />
            </param>
          </constructor>
        </typeConfig>
      </type>
```

more details on [msdn - Configuration Support for Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650698.aspx)

Comment: how would i constrain this to ICustomerAccountProvider though? because i eventually intend on having a number of channel factories for different types with different bindings, so i'm not sure this would work long term?

Comment: this work only if the ChannelFactory is a generic implementation of IChannelFactory. If you have several (not generic) channel factories you have to map each one to the specific implementation:  `<type name="customerChannelFactory"type="System.ServiceModel.Channels.IChannelFactory`1[MyNameSpace.ICustomerAccountProvider], System.ServiceModel" mapTo="MyNameSpace.CustomerChannelFactory, System.ServiceModel">`

Comment: this is intended to work with the generic `ChannelFactory<TChannel>`. I have tried your suggestion to no avail